# short/extensive training on computational chemistry

Tags: computational-chemistry

I want to take a training on computational works in chemistry. It should be of a short duration. Where in Europe I can find it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about chemistry, but about making a career in chemistry. I believe it is better asked at academia.se.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the offerings of the national chemical societies and their special interest groups?

In Germany, that would be the [CIC - Chemie Information Computer](https://www.gdch.de/netzwerk-strukturen/fachstrukturen/chemie-information-computer-cic.html) group of the [GDCh - Gesellschaft Deutscher Chemiker](https://www.gdch.de).

Cosmologic provides [TURBOMOLE workshops](http://www.cosmologic.de/support-download/workshops.html).

In 2014, the Max Planck Institute for Chemical Energy Conversion organized a [Summer School](http://www.cec.mpg.de/downloads/summer-school-2014.html) during which a course on QM/MM with Frank Neese's ORCA was given. I don't know if they plan something similar this year.

The [NSCCS](http://www.nsccs.ac.uk/events.php) has some upcoming events.